# The type or namespace name 'Portal' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Dynamics' (are you missing an assembly reference?

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, axapta, x++

I get the following error when creating new timesheets from the EP.

```
Message: An unhandled error has occurred. To view details about this error, enable debugging in the web.config file or view the Windows event logs. 

Source: App_Web_tstimesheetentrypage.ascx.91f2996b.w9xwqj0v
```

Exception details:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
at TSTimesheetEntryPage.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\ep\TSTimesheetEntryPage.ascx.cs:line 120
at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at AxBaseUserControl.OnLoad(EventArgs e) in c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\ep\AxBaseUserControl.ascx.cs:line 173
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean `enter code here`includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

In trying to get to the button of this I did the following:

1 ) In VS2013 I created a new Ax EP WebApplication project and added `\Web\Web Files\Web Controls\TSTimesheetEntryPage` to the project.This added 4 more dependent files to the project
3) Build the solution

Now I get compiler errors:

```
Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Portal' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Dynamics' (are you missing an assembly reference?) 
Error 2 The type or namespace name 'EPFormAction' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I tried resolving these errors by adding the `EPApplicationProxies` and the `TSTimesheetProxies` to the project by right clinking on my project select Add Ep Proxy project.However, the compiler starts to complain about  duplicate types.

```
'Microsoft.Dynamics.Portal.Application.Proxy.TSTimesheetLine' exists in both 'c:\Users\lawrence\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft Dynamics AX\C Sharp Projects\EPApplicationProxies\bin\Debug\EPApplicationProxies.dll' and 'c:\Users\lawrence\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft Dynamics AX\C Sharp Projects\TSTimesheetProxies\bin\Debug\TSTimesheetProxies.dll'    c:\users\lawrence.ntow\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\debugTimesheet\debugTimesheet\TSTimesheetEntryPage.ascx.cs     22  debugTimesheet
```

Any help will be much appreciated.